# Color swatch on collections page I Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

I have a shopify store and I added a color swatch palette to my shopify collections page .

**How do I display only the colors that are in stock?**

http://gloria22x.myshopify.com/collections/alle-produkte?sort_by=manual

Thanks, Alex

```
{% for option in product.options %}
{% if option == 'Color' %}
{% assign index = forloop.index0 %}
{% assign colorlist = '' %}
{% assign color = '' %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% capture color %}
{{ variant.options[index] }}
{% endcapture %}
{% unless colorlist contains color %}
<img class="colorpalette" src="{{ color | downcase | strip_newlines | strip_html | replace:'ß','ss' | remove: ' ' | append: '.png' | asset_url }}" title="{{ color | camelize }}" alt="{{ color | camelize }}" width="16" height="16"/>
{% capture tempList %}
{{colorlist | append: color | append: ‘ ‘}}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign colorlist = tempList %}
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the [`inventory_quantity`](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/variant#variant-inventory_quantity) for each variant. Try this:

```
...
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
...
```