# Show color swatches in facets on collection page using Instant Search Algolia

Tags: shopify, algolia, instantsearch.js

I would like to show color swatches on Shopify collection page facets that is controlled by Algolia instant search.

I read [algolia official facets type guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/shopify/getting-started/configuration/#facet-types), but not able to get the solution.

This is what i would like to show.

[image]

Does anyone know if this is possible, or how to go about it?

I posted to the algolia discourse, but did not get any answers on it.

https://discourse.algolia.com/t/to-show-color-swatches-in-facets-on-shopify-collection-page/11827

Already checked related questions but did not get what i wanted.

1. [Color swatch on collections page I Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496823/color-swatch-on-collections-page-i-shopify)
2. [Add color swatches to Collection page Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061811/add-color-swatches-to-collection-page-shopify)

Comment: might be this helpful in your case. https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/shopify/getting-started/upgrade-guides/collection-search-page-migration/?client=ruby

Comment: @onkar thanks.. but I already using upgraded version so no need to migrate those pages and JS.